# Xtable and Sweave

Tags: align, sweave, xtable

My question is regarding `xtable` and `sweave`.
I have a certain table created in RStudio and want to create a pdf file using it. 
I use the package Sweave and write the necessary code and I get the table. Unfortunately, the rownames of the table are aligned to the right instead to the left.
How can I avoid or rectify this?
Any suggestions would be well appreciated.

```
 \rowcolors{2}{white!65}{cyan!35}
 \begin{center}
 <<xtable1,results=tex,echo=FALSE>>=
 xtab<-xtable(ABC)
 print(xtab,center = "centering", floating=FALSE)
 @
 \end{center}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you do this, you need:

```
<<echo=false, results=hide>>= 
xtab <- xtable(ABC, align="lrrrrr")
@
```

the l will left align the row names. Please remember the align argument takes 1+ncol as the number of elements. So if you have 5 columns, you would do lrrrrr, if you have 4 columns, you would do lrrrr. Note: l=left, r=right, c=center.

Then,

```
<<echo=false, results=tex>>= 
print(xtab, floating=FALSE)
@
```

This should work. If you were using the knitr syntax, you would need, echo=FALSE, results='hide' and later, results='asis'